# What is the difference between Canon TS-E 24mm f/3.5L II and I?

Tags: lens, canon, tilt-shift

What are the major differences between version I and II of Canon 24mm tilt shift lens? Right now, used version I is half the price of II.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest operational difference is that version II has a super-rotator style design that allows the tilt and shift axis to be varied at any point relative to each other. Version I allowed the tilt and shift axes to be either aligned or set at 90 degrees to each other, and changing between the two settings required partially dismantling the lens! With version II there's just a knob to control the relative angles of tilt and shift.

The other main difference is the optics, version one of the 24mm tilt shift is 22 years old now and the new version was designed for digital and features a more sophisticated design (16 elements vs 11), with  modern coatings which bring a host of optical improvements. Extreme corners feature much improved contrast and sharpness, with less lateral chromatic aberration.

Alongside corner improvements the image circle is significantly larger (67.2mm compared to 58.6mm) allowing greater shifts and reduced vignetting. Maximum tilt is increased marginally to 8.5 degrees from 8. There is also a switch on the lens to lock tilt in the neutral position if you only want to shift.

You'll notice the differences if you do a lot of shifts. If you're mostly using the tilt function then version I is a good buy, though you might want to consider the Samyang 24mm tilt-shift which is a similar price but offers a super-rotator design. Performance is pretty bad wide open, but if you intend on using the lens to extend depth of field then it may perform better than the old Canon in the corners at f/8.

Comment: Have you seen a few of the early reviews for the Samyang/Rokinon/Bower/Pro-Optic/Walimax/whatever other name it is being sold as? It is dreadfully soft in the center, not to mention the corners, until stopped down past f/5.6.

Comment: @MichaelClark I saw the very first samples (which I attributed to operator error as they were so bad) and the largely inconclusive first review on lensrentals. Now I've read thedigitalpicture review which agrees with the trend that it is terrible wide open. It may still beat the old Canon in the corners when stopped down as it does have a larger image circle...

Comment: AT f/5.6 the Canon is still a bit sharper in the corners. By f/8 the Samyang is *barely* sharper than the original Canon. But below f/5.6 the Samyang doesn't look usable to me. Especially with the *TS rotate*, there a myriads of ways to use the lens that require wider apertures to tailor the shape of the plane of focus. http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=841&Camera=453&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=2&LensComp=347&CameraComp=453&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=2

Comment: I think that's unshifted though, want I want to see is the version I Canon fully shifted vs. the Samyang shifted the same amount to compare how quickly sharpness drops off when shifted. Still would have expected a bit more from Samyang given the reputation of their other lenses, this one seems over stretched.

Comment: I've seen charts with the Samyang shifted, but not the old Canon.

Comment: Are you sure the Samyang has super-rotator capability? It can rotate up to 90º between the mount and the shift mechanism, but based on all I've read it does not appear to have the capability to rotate between the shift movement and the tilt movement the way the TS-E 17mm f/4 L and TS-E 24mm f/3.5 L II can.

Comment: @MichaelClark I've not used the lens but all reports are that it can rotate between tilt and shift, from BHPhoto: *"To make the tilt-shift function even more seamless, both the lens mount as well as Tilt-Shift section may be rotated along the optical axis. The tilt-shift section can be rotated left by 90° (with 30° click-stop adjustment), while the lens mount may be rotated both in left and right direction by 90°, also with 30° adjustment."*

Answer (score 3):

The most significant difference is the ability of the TS-E 24mm f/3.5 L II to do *TS rotation*. This means that the relationship between the tilt axis and the shift axis can be altered from between 90º and 0º and *any point in between*. This can be accomplished on the fly during normal use of the lens. The original TS-E 24mm f/3.5 L can only be set at either 90º (standard orientation when the lens comes out of the factory) or 0º between the tilt and shift axes, and requires that the lens be partially disassembled to change the angle. This feature vastly expands the possibilities of how tilt and shift may both be used in combination to affect the perspective of an image. If you are interested in taking photos that only require either tilt or shift, but not both, then this feature is not much of a factor. If, on the other hand, you are interesting in discovering the full creative possibilities of a perspective control lens, then it is *revolutionary*.

The review of the [TS-E 24mm f/3.5 L II](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-TS-E-24mm-f-3.5-L-Tilt-Shift-Lens-Review.aspx) at [The-Digital-Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/) includes many comparisons to the original TS-E 24mm f/3.5 L it replaced in Canon's line up.

As the linked review above relates, the "II" version is also superior optically, especially in terms of sharpness and lack of chromatic aberration. If you look at the sample images the review provides, you can see that the differences are more than trivial - they are rather significant.